# Can this armor exist and how much would it cost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

*Mithral Chain Shirt +1 of Agility and Stamina*

Would this cost be right:

100  Base
1000 Masterwork/Mithral
1000 Magic
500  Agility
500  Stamina

3100 total?

The Agility and Stamina armor properties are found on pages 6 and 15 of the Magic Item Compendium. They add +1 resistance bonus to Reflex and Fortitude respectively. Also, they are not the equivalent of +1 bonuses so it is unclear to me if the prices grow exponentially if taken together if they can be taken together at all.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: The previous draft of the question was pretty bad. I downvoted the old version, but switched to an upvote after the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those properties are compatible with each other and are costed correctly.